# Failing to format my date to work correctly in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

Working on a PHP form that sends date I create a time/date from a input form. (jquery datepicker)

```
$dateinput = $_POST['datepicker'];
$t1 = date_create($dateinput);
//times are posted seperate and stipped from a input box (either 1055 or 10:55)
$t1_hour = substr($t1_raw,0,2);
$t1_min = substr($t1_raw,-2);

$t1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $t1_hour . 'H'));
$t1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $t1_min . 'M'));

print_r($t1);
```

This all seems to work

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2023-09-04 10:55:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam )
```

But when I try to pull the day of the yaer it fails to work with this data and returns nothing.

```
echo date('z',$t1);
```

I can print the information

```
$datetime_1 = date_format($t1, 'm-d-Y H:i'); 
echo $datetime_1;
```

Also works and returns: 09-04-2023 10:55

```
echo('z',$datetime_1);
```

returns 0

Where am I overlooking something?

```
print_r(getDate($datetime_1));
```

somehow is completely broken

```
Array ( 
[seconds] => 9 
[minutes] => 0 
[hours] => 1 
[mday] => 1 
[wday] => 4 
[mon] => 1 
[year] => 1970 
[yday] => 0 
[weekday] => Thursday 
[month] => January 
[0] => 9 
)
```

Comment: I guess the issue is that the date function expects the second parameter to be a Unix timestamp, but you are passing it a DateTime object. To get the day of the year from a DateTime object, you can use the format method of the DateTime object instead.

Comment: If you've got a DateTime object (which you have), just use its `->format()` function, rather than standalone `date()`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: @Jacco I recommend cleaning up your data payload so that your time values are consistent.  You can feed all of your data into the datetime object instantiation instead of adding the time components later. https://3v4l.org/S8ZZO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$dateinput = $_POST['datepicker'];
$t1 = date_create($dateinput);
//times are posted seperate and stipped from a input box (either 1055 or 10:55)
$t1_hour = substr($t1_raw,0,2);
$t1_min = substr($t1_raw,-2);

$t1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $t1_hour . 'H'));
$t1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $t1_min . 'M'));

print_r($t1);

// HERE: Use the format method of the DateTime object to get the day of the year
echo $t1->format('z');
```

EDIT:
Copied from my comment where I explain what I think could be causing the issue:

> I guess the issue is that the date function expects the second parameter to be a Unix timestamp, but you are passing it a `DateTime` object. To get the day of the year from a `DateTime` object,  instead you can use the format method of the `DateTime` object.